NavigationLink not functioning in SwiftUi for WatchOS
Hope you're having a great day.
I'm trying to build a simple page that navigates from one view to another, and I can't get the NavigationLinks to work even when following existing examples/documentation precisely.
Here is the source view:
import SwiftUI

struct HomePageView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            Color.mint
                .opacity(0.6)
                .ignoresSafeArea()
                .overlay{
                 
                    VStack{
                        Text("SomeText")
                            .padding()
                            .font(Font.custom("Ubuntu-Title", size: 18))
                        
                    }
            }
            NavigationLink(destination: DestinationView()){
                    Text("Navigate")
            }
        }
        
    }
}

struct HomePageView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        HomePageView()
    }
}

And the destination view:

import SwiftUI

struct DestinationView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            Text("SomeText")
        }
    }
}

struct DestinationView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        DestinationView()
    }
}

It renders correctly in the preview, but nothing happens when I click the navigation button. I've read from other sources that NavigationLink is broken for WatchOS; are there any alternatives?
I've tried moving around the NavigationLink in the home view (before/after the Vstack, etc). Nothing has worked so far. This is pretty much the out of the box implementation for the NavigationLink, so I'm not sure where else to go. Thanks in advance for any ideas!

You mention a VStack, but there is no VStack in your code. There is also no visible "Navigate" button on the app. When I run the app, it just shows "SomeText" with a mint background. As it is currently written, the NavigationView acts like a split view, among other problems.

try using only one NavigationStack instead of NavigationView, ie remove the one in DestinationView

Any tutorials, samples or tools that use NavigationView are outdated. Don't use them there are very few use cases for OS versions that require it.

Thank you all for your help so far!
Unfortunately, removing the NavigationView in the destination view didn't do the trick.
The VStack I mention is within an overlay on the first code block.
It's unfortunate that there's so much outdated documentation out there. Do you have a suggestion for an alternative that's in line with modern OS versions?
